# How to Integrate the jazzylistview Functionality to my android App

Tags: android, android-layout, jazzylistview

Can anyone help me how to integrate this library to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow sample application: https://github.com/twotoasters/JazzyListView/tree/master/sample